# How to relate user from "User Pool' (Cognito service) that sign up via app to manually created Thing(Iot Core Service)?

Tags: android, amazon-cognito, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I trying to figure out how to attach **Things**(virtual devices) that created in AWS Iot core console to specific user? or how to get **list of things** via android app? I currently using "AWSMobileClient.getInstance()" object to perform all my operation like: sign-up/sign-in and MQTT connection.

Comment: you can map the id of your things to a custom attribute in user pool

Comment: I created custom attribute in user pool but **I don't see** the custom attribute when I try to access them with "AWSMobileClient.getInstance().userAttributes" or via CLI Command "aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id xxxxxxxx --username xxxxxxxx." and I checked all the check boxes in "Set attribute read and write permissions"

Comment: `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getTokenString()` use this instead. I think the method you are using decodes the acess token which doesn't return custom attributes

Comment: How to get user custom attributes with this token? what api method I should use to get user custom attributes?

Comment: For example when I run the AWS cli command "aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id us-west-2_aaaaaaaaa --username jane@example.com" [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-get-user.html). I get all the attributes except the custom attributes and the custom attributes have Readable\Writable  permission in app clients